# List as Instance of show

Tags: haskell

Is there anyway to check how lists are instances of `Show`class. I have a datatype like this:

`data Graph a = Graph [a]` and i want to make it an instance of `Show` so that 
when i can call `show` function , i get only list and not the word Graph with it.

I tried this but i know this would not work because `show` returns a string and `x` is a list. I'm learning from *Learn you haskell for a great good*. There is no example, nor can I find any on internet.

```
instance Show (Graph a) where
    show (Graph x) = x
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `data Graph a = Graph [a]` rather than `newtype Graph a = Graph [a]`? The usual default for single-constructor, single-field types is `newtype`; we use `data` for those only when we need an extra bit of laziness for a special purpose.

Comment: @dfeuer It is the next section, i have not read that section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
instance Show a => Show (Graph a) where
    show (Graph x) = show x
```

We have to show the contained list, so we can't return `x`, but we must return `show x`. This, in turn, requires that the list `x` of type `[a]` is showable, so we need to require that using the `Show a => ...` context.

Comment: It's worth noting that although this *looks* like a recursive function, it is not. The `show` you call is totally different than the `show` you declare.

Comment: (But you should implement `showsPrec` instead of `show`.)

Answer (score 3):

Simply show the list:

```
show (Graph x) = show x
```